# How can I install Mercurial on my Windows Server 2003/08?

Tags: mercurial

I'd like to install Mercurial on my Windows Server. I can use either 2003/2008 depending on which is easiest to install on.

Thanks for the help fellow neckbeards!

Comment: HG works fine on windows server platforms - from the mercurial homepage there is a fine tutorial - http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/  under the tag - Getting Started

Comment: Also have a look at Superuser tag _ Mercurial - http://superuser.com/questions/176441/what-to-do-next-with-mercurial-after-i-install-it-in-my-pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's equally easy to install HG on Win2k3 and 2k8 (with the exception that you'll probably have to take the extra step on 2k8 to "run as administrator")

My favorite tutorial for Mercurial is Joel Spolsky's excellent [HGInit](http://hginit.com/)
The "Ground Up Mercurial" and "Setting Up For a Team" sections will be of the most use to you.

Comment: Can you share a tutorial or something? I'm in the dark here. Thanks!

Comment: Edited answer to add links for you.  They're not specific to installation, but it's a very down-n-dirty tutorial.  The basic installer is a typical windows install.  Double-click, next, next, finish.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with Hg on Windows, but [TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/) has worked for me very well so far. It has a nice built-in server and a powerful GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [HgLab](http://hglabhq.com/). This is a purely managed Mercurial implementation with push and pull server and repository browser.